# mongodb group and count, match and update the other fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this following field

e_id, c_id, m_id in mongodb that must be match on the 
id pass by parameter.

data -> is multiple event_id, coor_id, manage_id

```
  {
        "_id" : "1",
        "event_id" : "abscdsadsad890",
        "coor_id" : "cdaddsadewqwae889",
        "manage_id" : "fdfdfsdfdsfsdf908",
        "active" : true
        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00Z"),
    }

     {
        "_id" : "1",
        "event_id" : "abscdsadsad890",
        "coor_id" : "cdaddsadewqwae889",
        "manage_id" : "fdfdfsdfdsfsdf908",
        "active" : true
        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00Z"),
    }

 {
        "_id" : "1",
        "event_id" : "abscdsadsad890",
        "coor_id" : "cdaddsadewqwae889",
        "manage_id" : "fdfdfsdfdsfsdf908",
        "active" : true
        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00Z"),
    }
```

expected result :

```
  {
            "_id" : "1",
            "event_id" : "abscdsadsad890",
            "coor_id" : "cdaddsadewqwae889",
            "manage_id" : "fdfdfsdfdsfsdf908",
            "active" : true
            "date" : ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00Z"),
        }

         {
            "_id" : "1",
            "event_id" : "abscdsadsad890",
            "coor_id" : "cdaddsadewqwae889",
            "manage_id" : "fdfdfsdfdsfsdf908",
            "active" : false
            "date" : ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00Z"),
        }

     {
            "_id" : "1",
            "event_id" : "abscdsadsad890",
            "coor_id" : "cdaddsadewqwae889",
            "manage_id" : "fdfdfsdfdsfsdf908",
            "active" : false
            "date" : ISODate("2014-01-14T00:00:00Z"),
        }
```

the expected result should make the non-latest
record to be active false and the most latest 
one must be active every created new record the
new record should be active = true and other 
the same event_id, coor_id and manage_id must 
be active = false

I am trying to use match all result, then group and count, 
after that if count is greater than 1, get the latest document found result 
and update the rest match result but in mongodb 
I want to write that as well. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Akrion : I update the question and expected result as well, but also if only one record is find it should stay active as well if more than 1 then the old one will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it by c#

first is I pass the event_id, coor_id and manage_id in
create. Then using c# mongodb driver i did is

```
var list = await collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => c.id == c.id && m.id == m.id).toList();
```

then loop and check the first one must not equal to others by _id

then update others except the first list.

Done... Thanks